# Recursive join rows n with n+1 - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query

I'm trying to get some KPIs from v$servicemetric_history in Oracle DB.

```
Name              Null? Type              
----------------- ----- ----------------- 
BEGIN_TIME              DATE              
END_TIME                DATE              
INTSIZE_CSEC            NUMBER            
GROUP_ID                NUMBER            
SERVICE_NAME_HASH       NUMBER            
SERVICE_NAME            VARCHAR2(64 BYTE) 
CTMHASH                 NUMBER            
ELAPSEDPERCALL          NUMBER            
CPUPERCALL              NUMBER            
DBTIMEPERCALL           NUMBER            
CALLSPERSEC             NUMBER            
DBTIMEPERSEC            NUMBER            
CON_ID                  NUMBER
```

I want to link rows n and n+1 with
TRUNC(END_TIME, 'mi') = TRUNC(BEGIN_TIME, 'mi')
and get some percentage KPIs on CPUPERCALL :

1. % difference between CPUPERCALL on row n and row n+1 : I've done that with LAG function : LAG(cpupercall) OVER(ORDER BY begin_time) AS last_cpupercall to get the CPUPERCALL value from last row then I can calculate the KPI with the formula because both values are on same row ( ( cpupercall- last_cpupercall ) / last_cpupercall * 100 ) AS pct_cpupercall
2. % difference between CPUPERCALL on row n and AVG(CPUPERCALL) on all dataset. I found a solution with a FULL JOIN to get the AVG(cpupercall) on same row then I just have to calculate the KPI the same way as the previous.

Sample datas:

```
BEGIN_TIME  END_TIME    CPUPERCALL
3/11/2022 2:51 PM   3/11/2022 2:52 PM   558,3312861
3/11/2022 2:50 PM   3/11/2022 2:51 PM   703,4087634
3/11/2022 2:49 PM   3/11/2022 2:50 PM   528,9117155
3/11/2022 2:48 PM   3/11/2022 2:49 PM   1007,740599
3/11/2022 2:47 PM   3/11/2022 2:48 PM   1033,231789
```

My query :

```
SELECT
begin_time,
end_time,
cpupercall,
last_cpupercall,
avg_cpupercall,
( (cpupercall - last_cpupercall) / last_cpupercall * 100 ) AS pct_cpupercall,
( (cpupercall - avg_cpupercall) / avg_cpupercall * 100 ) AS pct_avg_cpupercall
FROM (
SELECT 
begin_time,
end_time,
cpupercall,
LAG(cpupercall) OVER(ORDER BY begin_time) as last_cpupercall,
avg_cpupercall
FROM
v$servicemetric_history
FULL JOIN (SELECT AVG(cpupercall) as avg_cpupercall FROM v$servicemetric_history) ON 1=1
)
```

Tanks

EDIT : I found a solution with LAG and FULL JOIN to get all datas I needed for KPIs calculation on same row, but it might exist some simple way to do this.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: a minimal set of data (do you really need 13 columns? can you simplify the problem and create a minimal example with 4 or 5 columns?); **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution; a description of the problem including what you want to calculate (what do you mean by KPI? and what values are the percentage(s) of?); and the expected output for your sample data.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want, but it sounds like analytic functions might be helpful: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions

Comment: Hi, I've edited the post to be more clear and simple. I also found a way to get my first KPI known as "percertage between row n and row n+1". My issue is now on getting the 2nd KPI known as "percentage delta of row n and average of full dataset". And maybe I'm going in the bad direction with this the LAG function.

Comment: Haven't you already done it with "( (cpupercall - avg_cpupercall) / avg_cpupercall * 100 ) AS pct_avg_cpupercall"?